# PHP - Checking a file has been uploaded but the rest of the information is empty

Tags: php

I have a form which asks for an image uploaded, title, description etc.

An error appears if no image is selected like this:

```
if ($_FILES["target_file"]==''){

echo 'Please upload a suitable photograph!<br>';

}
```

But if i select an image but don't fill in the rest of the form, it will upload it to my database.

I've tried something like this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['target_file']) && (empty ($_POST['photo-title'])) && (empty ($_POST['photo-name'])) && (empty ($_POST['uploaded'])) && (empty ($_POST['genreID'])) && (empty ($_POST['description'])))
{
   echo 'Please select a photograph!<br>';
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Any one any ideas on how i can make it display an error after selecting an image but not filling the rest of the form?

Comment: Does your form use `enctype="multipart/form-data" `?

Comment: Is all fields are textboxes/textarea or there is any radio or checkbox ?

Comment: There is one dropdown menu included in the form @Pinu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['target_file']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['target_file']['tmp_name'])){
    echo 'Please upload an image!<br>';
} else if(empty($_POST['photo-title']) || empty($_POST['photo-name']) || empty($_POST['uploaded']) || empty($_POST['genreID']) || empty($_POST['description'])){
    echo 'Please fill in all the input fields!<br>';
} else {
    //upload everything
}
```

In your code, you used `&&`, which means that the error would only echo if *all* the fields were empty. Also, the exclamation mark in front of `empty($_FILES['target_file'])` means that you will get an error if there *is* a file, and no error when there isn't.

Also, it's not necessary to enclose every `empty(/*post field*/)` part in brackets

Comment: Tried this @Jonan and it doesn't seem to be working properly.  It shows the error "Please upload an image!" even though an image has been selected.

Comment: Even when all areas are filled out, it still says "Please upload an image!" @Jonan

Comment: @jordan does it work with `!isset()` instead of `empty()`? Could you maybe `var_dump($_FILES)` and tell we the contents when the file is uploaded?

Comment: @Jordan what do you get when put `var_dump($_FILES)` at the top of your page?

Comment: this is what i get when i select an image: `array(1) { ["uploaded"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Desert.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(32) "D:\HND\UniServer\tmp\php67B1.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(845941) } } Please upload an image! `

Comment: this is what i get when i dont select anything:  `array(1) { ["uploaded"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } } Please upload an image!`

Comment: @Jordan Please make sure you have set the `name` attribute for the file input element - and see my updated answer